# Subir archivo y renombrarlo y agregarle serie en php

Tags: php

estoy haciendo un formulario básico para subir archivos de imágenes donde le pongo el nombre que seria su código y le agrego un numero de secuencia.

Ejemplo: Código 12345. Subiría como 12345_01.jpg, 12345_02.jpg, 12345_03.jpg, etc según el código que se ingrese en el campo del formulario.
El archivo index.php

```
<?php
session_start(); 
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>PHP File Upload</title>
</head>
<body>
  <?php
    if (isset($_SESSION['message']) && $_SESSION['message'])
    {
      printf('<b>%s</b>', $_SESSION['message']);
      unset($_SESSION['message']);
    }
  ?>
  <form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <label class="description" for="element_1">Código </label>
        <div>
            <input id="codigo" name="codigo" class="element text medium" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_2" >
        <label class="description" for="element_2">Numero Inicio </label>
        <div>
            <input id="ninicio" name="ninicio" class="element text small" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 
        </li>       <li id="li_3" >
        <label class="description" for="element_3">Numero Final </label>
        <div>
            <input id="nfinal" name="nfinal" class="element text small" type="text" maxlength="255" value=""/> 
        </div> 

    <div>
      <span>Upload a File:</span>
      <input type="file" name="uploadedFile" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" name="uploadBtn" value="Upload" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

el archivo upload.php

```
<?php
session_start();

$message = ''; 
if (isset($_POST['uploadBtn']) && $_POST['uploadBtn'] == 'Upload')
{
  if (isset($_FILES['uploadedFile']) && $_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK)
  {
    // get details of the uploaded file
    $fileTmpPath = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['tmp_name'];
    $fileName = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['name'];
    $fileSize = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['size'];
    $fileType = $_FILES['uploadedFile']['type'];
    $fileNameCmps = explode(".", $fileName);
    $fileExtension = strtolower(end($fileNameCmps));

    // sanitize file-name
    $codigof = $_POST['codigo'];
  
    $newFileName = $codigof . '.' . $fileExtension;

    // check if file has one of the following extensions
    $allowedfileExtensions = array('jpg', 'gif', 'png', 'zip', 'txt', 'xls', 'doc');

    if (in_array($fileExtension, $allowedfileExtensions))
    {
      // directory in which the uploaded file will be moved
      $uploadFileDir = './uploaded_files/';
      $dest_path = $uploadFileDir . $newFileName;

      if(move_uploaded_file($fileTmpPath, $dest_path)) 
      {
        $message ='File is successfully uploaded.';
      }
      else 
      {
        $message = 'There was some error moving the file to upload directory. Please make sure the upload directory is writable by web server.';
      }
    }
    else
    {
      $message = 'Upload failed. Allowed file types: ' . implode(',', $allowedfileExtensions);
    }
  }
  else
  {
    $message = 'There is some error in the file upload. Please check the following error.<br>';
    $message .= 'Error:' . $_FILES['uploadedFile']['error'];
  }
}
$_SESSION['message'] = $message;
header("Location: index.php");
```

Como podría hacerlo? por ejemplo en el formulario tendo 2 campos mas porque la imagen tiene que repetirse x veces. En el campo inicio pongo 01 y en el final 6 la imagen con el código 12345 tendría que ser 1234501 así hasta repetirlo 6 veces la misma imagen 1234502, 1234503, 1234504, 1234505, 1234506. Agregando el 0x al final las veces que le pongo en el segundo campo.
Saludos

Comment: lee los archivos y los pasas a un array, cuentas cuantos archivos empiezan por el numero digitado y después al recultado le agregas un 1 y escribes el nombre, pero te aconsejo mejor tener una tabla en la base y leer los registros con ese numero y después agregas el nuevo sumando uno es mucho mas rapido.

Comment: Gracias justo estaba editando la pregunta porque creo que no me explique bien lo que deseaba porque hasta yo me hice un lio en un principio.

Comment: Tienes muchas formas, te voy a nombrar tres, puedes llevar un campo control en tu registro principal, donde sabes la cantidad de fotos que llevas guardada, la otra es contar cuantas fotos hay en un directorio cuyos primeros caracteres coinciden con el id de la foto y tercero guardar en una tabla control los registros y detalles de las fotos... Todas estas soliciones van a depender de tu regla del manejo de las imagenes (si vas a borrarlas, mantenerlas etc).

Comment: Hola gracias, si se van a mantener el problema es que van a ser muchas fotos, porque son un producto el cual tiene 6 fotos del mismo producto porque son diferentes ángulos por ejemplo, el 6 es un ejemplo pueden ser 10 o la cantidad de ángulos que sean, entonces ese código del producto va a tener varias copias que no se sabe dependiendo del producto por lo que una foto seria 1234501_01 otra 1234501_02 y si se duplica 1234502_01 y así. ya voy a leer bien lo que me comentan porque se me hizo un lio la cabeza con esto.

Answer (score 0):

Recomiendo separar el problema en partes. Crea una función que obtenga el nombre del próximo archivo, comparando contra los que ya existen:

```php
<?php

define('UPLDIR', './uploaded_files/');

function get_next_name($pattern, $ext) {
    $matches = glob(UPLDIR . $pattern . '_*.' . $ext); // [*]
    if($matches) {
        sort($matches);
        $last_file = end($matches);
        $file_num = intval(substr($last_file, strrpos($last_file, '_')+1, 2));
        $next_num = str_pad(++$file_num, 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    } else {
        $next_num = '01';
    }
    return $pattern . '_' . $next_num . '.' . $ext;
}
```

Según el código que ya tienes, hay una variable con el *código del nombre* y otra con la *extensión*. Entonces le envías esos parámetros a la función:

```php
$codigof = '1234'; // ** [!] Valor de prueba
$fileExtension = 'jpg'; // ** [!] Valor de prueba

// Suponiendo están los archivos '1234_01.jpg', '1234_02.jpg', '1234_05.jpg'
$newFileName = get_next_name($codigof, $fileExtension); // 1234_06.jpg
// ... Resto del código
```

[*] Lectura recomendada: buscar archivos por patrones: [glob()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.glob.php)